# Windows 7 doesn't show image size for all images

Tags: windows-7, images, png

On Windows 7's new file layout in Explorer. Some PNGs will show the size whereas others won't. I've tried rebooting and clearing the cache, but it doesn't work. Also, all of these images were saved with Paint.NET, so I am sure that the size isn't embeded in the file, and if it is, it appears that Windows doesn't go by it. The ones without sizes are 300x300. Is there a maximum size before it won't show the size anymore?

[image]

Comment: What are the full file names, including extension?

Comment: they all end in .png

Comment: @MikeFitzpatrick volMin.png and volMax.png are the 16x16. The other ones are 300x300 are keyOverlay.png, keyHighlightInner.png and keyHighlightOuter.png. The ones that arn't marked are the XNA Project files

Comment: My guess would be that it has to do with PNG files' encoding, e.g. compressing, interlacing, resolution, etc. Windows may not know how to analyze more "complex" PNGs. What options did you choose when exporting/saving to PNG?

Comment: Can you upload the images?

Comment: By "image size", do you mean **dimensions**? Do they show correctly in thumbnail view? Do they have timestamps? (some of the items in your screenshot do not seem to)

Comment: @Synetech yes, dimensions. As I said in my other comment, the ones not marked as PNG are the XNA content project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without you uploading the png's in question it's hard to say for sure but it could be missing EXIF metadata or metadata on layers instead of the document itself, or foreign language characters used. In `Paint.net` you can create PNG's without Exif metadata eg by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> and saving the new PNG. Also there are a lot of metadata strippers meant to delete metadata to e.g. cut filesize. Load the PNG in a program to check if they do or not have metadata.

Answer (score 1):

A good answer requires some example images, both small and large, so we can compare their attributes. The type of an image is normally determined from its contents, not from its file-suffix, so that a .gif image can be named .png, but may still be displayed correctly (still depending on the smartness of the display program).

One registry hack I know that enables an image type in Explorer is as follows :

Go to `Start -> Run` and type `regedit` and click OK to launch the registry editor. Navigate to the registry key `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.png` and ensure that the `PerceivedType` string value is present and its value is set to `image` :

[image]